# get primary and secondary site administrators using javascript

Tags: 2010, javascript, sharepoint-server

Trying to retrieve the primary and secondary site administrators using javascript and show them in the labels on custom Access Denied page. Using the code below(inline javascript) to do that but `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(myfunction, "sp.js");` (also used `SP.SOD.ExcuteFunc()` but of no use) does not get executed. Am I missing something?

```
<asp:Content ID="Content5" ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">

<script type="text/javascript">
    SP.SOD.registerSod("sp.js", "\_layouts\SP.js");

   // RegisterSodDep("inplview", "sp.js");
        debugger;
        alert("begin");
        var currentContext;




        alert("before method");


            ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(myfunction, "sp.js");


            function myfunction() {
            alert("Entering into function");
            currentContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            //alert("1");
            var siteColl = clientContext.get_site();
            var rootWeb = siteColl.get_rootWeb();
            this.props = rootWeb.get_allProperties();

            clientContext.load(rootWeb);
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onRequestSucceeded, onRequestFailed);
            //alert("end");
        }

        alert("after method");


        //alert("After");
        function onRequestSucceeded() {
            alert("inside onrequest");
            var primarySiteContact = this.props.get_item('GA_PrimarySiteCollectionContact');
            var secondarySiteContact = this.props.get_item('GA_SecondarySiteCollectionContact');
            var elem = document.getElementById('lblPrimary');
            elem.innerHTML = primarySiteContact;
            alert(primarySiteContact);
            var elem2 = document.getElementById('lblSecondary');
            elem2.innerHTML = secondarySiteContact;
            alert(secondarySiteContact);
        }

        function onRequestFailed(sender, args) {
            alert('Error: ' + args.get_message());
        }

 </script>
```

Comment: SharePoint version? 2010 or 2013

Comment: I am working on sharepoint 2010

Comment: Did u try `_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("myfunction");`

Comment: Hey Atish, tried _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("myfunction"); ..it did enter the function but now getting the error "Unable to get property 'get_current' of undefined or null reference"

Answer (score 0):

Change your `SP.SOD.registerSod("sp.js", "\_layouts\SP.js");` to `SP.SOD.registerSod("sp.js", "/_layouts/sp.js");`. You need to use forward slashes instead of backslashes.

Also, try using `SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.js", "SP.ClientContext", myfunction);` instead of `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(myfunction, "sp.js");`.

Comment: **OP** said his SharePoint version is 2010.

Comment: Hi Atish, tried SP.SOD.registerSod("sp.js", "/_layouts/SP.js");  but it did not work

Comment: @Tarun K: Check my updated answer.

Comment: @MihailPopa tried using SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.js", false, myfunction); but unfortunately it did not work and shows no error while debugging

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code:

```
var ctx;

 SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', sharePointReady);
 function sharePointReady () {

                ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
                var siteColl = ctx.get_site();
                var rootWeb = siteColl.get_rootWeb();
                this.props =  rootWeb.get_allProperties();
                ctx.load(rootWeb);
                ctx.load(this.props); //need to load the properties explicitly

                ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, gotProperty), Function.createDelegate(this, failedGettingProperty));

}


            function gotProperty() {                
                 var policy = this.props.get_item('GA_PolicyDisplayName');
                 var primarySiteContact = this.props.get_item('GA_PrimarySiteCollectionContact');
                 var secondarySiteContact = this.props.get_item('GA_SecondarySiteCollectionContact');

                 elem = document.getElementById('ga-sitecontact');//Pass your desired object
                 elem.innerHTML = "<b>Policy:</b> " + policy  + " <b>Primary Contact:</b> " + primarySiteContact  + " <b>Secondary Contact:</b> " + secondarySiteContact;
            }

            function failedGettingProperty() {
                // swallow
            }
```

Reference:

- http://www.jeremythake.com/2013/10/using-the-sharepoint-csom-api-to-get-a-property-bag-value/

Hope this will help you.

Comment: tried the code provided by you but it does not go past  ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(SetGASiteContactInner, "sp.js"); hence SetGASiteContactInner() does not get executed

Comment: Please new updated code

Comment: tried the updated solution provided by you. It seems that SP.SOD.executeFunc('SP.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function() does not run somehow due to which SP.js is not loaded